# jquery hide/show not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a set of radio buttons and a div.  When the page loads, I do not want the div visible, and when button 1-3 is selected, I want the div to show.  When button 4 or 5 is selected, I don't want the div to show.

I currently have it working in all browser with the exception of IE (surprise).  I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.  I used firebug and there are no errors.  Here's what I have:

HTML:
-the buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="bWaitTime" value="1" id="group_name_0"/>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="bWaitTime" value="2" id="group_name_1"/>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="bWaitTime" type="radio"  value="3" id="group_name_2"/>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="bWaitTime"  value="4" id="group_name_3"/>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="bWaitTime"  value="5" id="group_name_4"/>
```

-the div to hide

```
<div id="yes_box">
<!--Content Here -->
</div>
```

And here is the script I have, which is currently residing inside the div #yes_box

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

          window.onload = $(function(){
                              var myDiv = $("#yes_box");
                              myDiv.hide();
                            });

          $(function(){

          var myDiv = $("#yes_box");

              $("input#group_name_0").change(function(){
                  myDiv.show('slow');  
              });
              $("input#group_name_1").change(function(){
                  myDiv.show('slow');  
              });
              $("input#group_name_2").change(function(){
                  myDiv.show('slow');  
              });
              $("input#group_name_3").change(function(){
                  myDiv.hide('slow');  
              });
              $("input#group_name_4").change(function(){
                  myDiv.hide('slow');  
              });

          });

          </script>
```

I've seen this exact method used elsewhere, and it had no problems with IE, however, in my use, it doesn't function at all. IE completely ignores it.

Comment: Try removing the `window.onload = $(function()` and do everything inside the DOM ready statement below.

Comment: what version of IE are you having issues with?  Works fine in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/bHWws/

Comment: Several people saying it's working for them. Is it possible the problem is because the div to show/hide is inside a table, inside the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `jQuery`'s *.ready()* method instead of *window.onload*

```
      $( document ).ready( function() {
          var myDiv = $("#yes_box");
          myDiv.hide();

          $("input#group_name_0").change(function(){
              myDiv.show('slow');  
          });
          $("input#group_name_1").change(function(){
              myDiv.show('slow');  
          });
          $("input#group_name_2").change(function(){
              myDiv.show('slow');  
          });
          $("input#group_name_3").change(function(){
              myDiv.hide('slow');  
          });
          $("input#group_name_4").change(function(){
              myDiv.hide('slow');  
          });

      });
```

**Edit:**

Furthermore, you may replace all *.change()* events with a single one, if all the ids match the "group_name_n" pattern:

```
      $("input[id^=group_name_]").change(function(){
          myDiv.show('slow');  
      });
```

Comment: That should not be a problem.. One can assign teh event in load event

Comment: Right, but it's still a better practice to use .ready() instead of window.onload

Comment: There are some instances when you want to use $(window).load instead of DOM Ready .. If the DOM ready is too soon

Comment: Haven't been in that situation before, but of course you're right. :)

Comment: Anyone writing the OP's code probably wouldn't be making that distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Think the problem is here in this line

```
window.onload = $(function() {
```

supposed to be

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

It may not help in solving the issue. You can condense your event handler to a single handler..

And use either `$(window).load()`  or `DOM Ready` .. both are not necessary here

Hide it initially using **CSS**

```
​#yes_box
{
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var myDiv = $("#yes_box");
    myDiv.hide();

    $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
        var val = this.value;
        if (val == 1 || val == 2 || val == 3) {
            myDiv.show('slow');
        }
        else {
            myDiv.hide('slow');
        }
    });
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nNwSV/1/)**

Comment: there is `var myDiv = $("#yes_box");` inside the $(function()

Comment: oops.. @wirey .. Did,t see that

Comment: @andrux . I thought I removed that part .. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're passing a jQuery object to `window.onload`, which expects a function, like

```
window.onload = function(){
    var myDiv = $("#yes_box");
    myDiv.hide();
};
```

If you want an element hidden when a page loads wouldn't it be better to do it with css, or when the DOM is ready which fires before window load.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified code would be (*since your code works fine for IE7,8,9 on my system*)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

      var myDiv = $("#yes_box").hide();

      $('input[name="bWaitTime"]').change(function(){
          var value = parseInt(this.value,10);
          if (value>=1 && value <=3){
              myDiv.show('slow'); 
          } else {
              myDiv.hide('slow'); 
          }
      });
  });
  </script>
```